# how to remove Syntax error for constraints in pulp in python

Tags: python, optimization, syntax, constraints, pulp

The below code shows syntax error after for loop at this line

```
model += x[int((str((i*2)-1)+str(j)))] + x[int((str(i*2)+str(j)))]] <= 1
```

i want the variable to be declared like 2 D array x11, x12,x13 am i getting error because of this.

```
KeyError   
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-19b3a6e81910> in <module>()
     19 for i in range (1, (Box//2)+1):
     20      for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
---> 21        model += x[int((str((i*2)-1)+str(j)))] + x[int((str(i*2)+str(j)))] <= 1
     22 
     23 

KeyError: 11
```

i checked all possible option everything seems right someone please help.

'''

```
from pulp import *
Box=6
Pallet=3
Variable_range=Box*Pallet

from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable
# Define the model
model = LpProblem(name="Container Loading", sense=LpMaximize)

# Define the decision variables
for i in range(1, Box+1):
    for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
      x = {int((str(i)+str(j))):LpVariable(name=f"x{i}_{j}",lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat='Integer')}
      print(x)

# Add constraints
for i in range (1, (Box//2)+1):
     for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
       model += x[int((str((i*2)-1)+str(j)))] + x[int((str(i*2)+str(j)))]] <= 1 # error at this line
        

#Set the objective
model += lpSum(x.values())

# Solve the optimization problem
status = model.solve()

# Get the results
print(f"status: {model.status}, {LpStatus[model.status]}")
print(f"objective: {model.objective.value()}")

for var in x.values():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")


for name, constraint in model.constraints.items():
    print(f"{name}: {constraint.value()}")
```

'''

Comment: Why is there `<= 1`  at the end?

Comment: i am planning to neglect any one of the variable  to exist in the problem or both to be neglected. hence sum of 1 should be less than 1 deals with that condition

Comment: In this case `x[int((str((i*2)-1)+str(j)))] + x[int((str(i*2)+str(j)))]] <= 1` will be evaluated first. It will return true or false. So `model += (True or False) ` will happed. In other word `model += (1 or 0)` based on condition, will happed. Is that waht you want to do?

Comment: Also what syntax error do you get? Edit your question to include that.

Comment: The line in question has a superfluous `]`. It also has some unnecessary pairs of round brackets, which affect readability if not syntactic validity.

Comment: thanks alani !                                                                                                    
KeyError                                                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-19b3a6e81910> in <module>()
     19 for i in range (1, (Box//2)+1):
     20      for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
---> 21        model += x[int((str((i*2)-1)+str(j)))] + x[int((str(i*2)+str(j)))] <= 1
     22 
     23 

KeyError: 11  please help to solve this

Comment: @M.LakshmiNarayananLAK include this errors in question itself and don't comment them.

Comment: To be honest, I would create other variables to break it up a bit, e.g. `index1 = int(str((i*2)-1)+str(j))` then `index2 = int(str(i*2)+str(j))` then `model += x[index1] + x[index2] <= 1`

Comment: @alani Same error tried this also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code below. I have changed the style of defining of decision variables. It is not throwing error.

```
from pulp import *
Box=6
Pallet=3
Variable_range=Box*Pallet
x = {}
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable
# Define the model
model = LpProblem(name="Container Loading", sense=LpMaximize)

# Define the decision variables
for i in range(1, Box+1):
    for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
      x[(i,j)] = pulp.LpVariable('x' + str(i) + '_' + str(j), 0, 1, LpBinary)
      print(x[(i,j)])

# Add constraints
for i in range (1, (Box//2)+1):
     for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
       model += x[(i*2-1,j)] + x[(i*2,j)] <= 1 # error at this line
        

#Set the objective
model += lpSum(x.values())

# Solve the optimization problem
status = model.solve()
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is my first attempt to post in forum and i am learning from today. its been a great motivation

Answer (score 1):

This is about misunderstanding loops. In:

```
# Define the decision variables
for i in range(1, Box+1):
    for j in range (1,Pallet+1):
      x = {int((str(i)+str(j))):LpVariable(name=f"x{i}_{j}",lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat='Integer')}

print(x)
```

you each time overwrite x. So you end up x containing just one element. You can see this by moving the print statement to after the loop.

Better is:

```
# Define the decision variables
x = {int((str(i)+str(j))):LpVariable(name=f"x{i}_{j}",lowBound=0,upBound=1,cat='Integer') 
        for i in range(1, Box+1) for j in range (1,Pallet+1) }

print(x)
```